# Null for a decimal type of column BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, null, decimal

```
   cast(sum(case
            when x.product = 'APPLE' and x.colour ='RED'then round(x.price1,2)

           when x.product <>  'APPLE' then **'NULL'**
           ELSE 0
         end) as decimal) as price,
```

`price` column is of type `decimal`. But I want to give an output as Null for only this second when statement instead of decimal value.

How can I do that?

Comment: select x.product, cast(sum(case
when x.product = 'Apple' and x.colour ='RED'then round(x.price,2)



when x.product <> 'Apple' then NULL
ELSE 0
end) as decimal) as price

Comment: Hi @Mohammad , I have raised another question regarding bigquery. can you please check and help me on that , please?

Comment: Replied on that thread. Thanks for reaching out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have simple NULL. It should work as below.

```
select cast(sum(case
when x.product = 'Apple' and x.colour ='RED'then round(x.price,2)



when x.product <> 'Apple' then NULL
ELSE 0
end) as decimal) as price
```

Comment: this gives me 0 as an output if x.product <> 'Apple'. I want NULL in the output

Comment: Thank you. It worked. there is another sub table which has some logic for the same column. I have updated the logic as you mentioned there as well.